# oauth_problem=consumer_key_rejected using Scribe library

Tags: java, yahoo, scribe

I registed for a Yahoo Messenger SDK api and plugged-in the consumer key/sercret into this code:

https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/YahooExample.java

However, I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this: 'oauth_problem=consumer_key_rejected'
    at org.scribe.extractors.TokenExtractorImpl.extract(TokenExtractorImpl.java:41)
    at org.scribe.extractors.TokenExtractorImpl.extract(TokenExtractorImpl.java:27)
    at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getRequestToken(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:52)
    at com.yahoodemo.YahooExample.main(YahooExample.java:28)
```

I'm pretty sure that the consumer key/secret is correct because I can get the 'RequestToken' using the same key/secret with a generic HTTP GET request.

Is this a bug in the Scribe library or it's something else?

Comment: have you tried enabling the `debug` flag? have you contacted Yahoo! forums?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even i faced the same problem. But i finally found that: 
In developer accounts (http://developer.apps.yahoo.com/projects) After creating the project, Don`t forgot to give alteast one permission for the application like: Contacts - READ, Knowledge Plus- READ. Finally save

Answer (score 1):

The solution from Nagendra worked for me but don't forget to refresh the Yahoo Project page as both the key and the secret code are changed after editing the permissions.